How to calculate the numerical integration and plot the result in python?
I am trying to solve the question below in McQuarrie Physical-Chemistry book.

The first step of the exercise, I solved. However, the second step involves a numerical integration. I can develop a code for a trapezoidal rule, but I don't know how could I interact with all the results presented in the first plot.

How could I do this in python? Any suggestions?

You have a function table. You can use interpolation functions like numpy.interp or scipy.interpolate.interp1d to convert these into a function and generate a function table for a different, finer grid. Or use the functions in an ODE integrator from scipy.integrate to get the integral function. Also check out the quadrature functions if they provide cumulative or progressive integration.
